# Is Zero Register 'zr' in aarch64 essentially ground?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, arm64, zero

Recently started messing with AArch64 assembly and I noticed that it has an assigned register strictly for *zero*, whereas (most) other architectures you would just `xor var, var`.

The site I was reading about `zr` explained it as a *reference point for zero* which sounds a lot like how I define ground in DC electronics. And because ARM is used by hobbyists, tying ground in the circuit to zero in the code kinda makes sense to me.

I'm sure it's much more complex than this, but is this a safe analogy to make? And would using this register compared to other ways of getting '0' result in different outcomes?

Comment: `whereas (most) other architectures you would just 'xor var, var'` actually most modern (read: from the 1980s onward) architectures are RISC and have a dedicated zero register, for exampe [MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12541443/995714)

Comment: ARM CPUs that implement the AArch64 architecture are complex CPUs. They include CPUs that are probably as complex as any CPU that doesn't execute the x86 instruction set. They're not designed for hobbyists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The zero register `xzr` resp. `wzr` is a cute design trick in the Aarch64 ISA.  It's register number is 31, just as the stack pointer `sp` resp. `wsp`.  Depending on the context, register number 31 refers to one of them.

This cute trick allows the Aarch64 ISA to simplify its instruction set.  For example, the `cmp xn, xm` instruction is actually `subs xzr, xn, xm`, i.e. it's a subtraction with the result being discarded.  A `mov xn, xm` is simply an `orr xn, xzr, xm`, i.e. a bitwise-or of the source with zero.  Register 31 is only recognised as the stack pointer where it makes sense and the instruction set has been cleverly chosen so you almost never hit on this limitation.

Answer (score 6):

> Is Zero Register 'zr' in aarch64 essentially ground? ... is this a safe analogy to make?

No. There are all sorts of hardware logic out there. **Whether the zero register's bits are connected to ground or not is unimportant since it's just an *implementation detail***. You only need to think of it as the numeric value zero and what happens if we read or write that register. Don't think about the underlying circuits when you're working in software

For example many architectures might use inverted logic ([active-low](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level#Active_state)) with 0V means logic 1, then the **zero register will actually connect to V<sub>cc</sub>**. Or some others use balanced logic where logic 0 and 1 are represented by −V<sub>cc</sub> and V<sub>cc</sub> respectively. In that case the **zero register will be connected to −V<sub>cc</sub>** and it's not ground either.

---

But why have a zero register?

The general RISC philosophy is to *avoid memory access in every instruction*, instead **only load/store instructions are allowed to touch memory**. As a result, RISC architectures need *a lot* of registers to reduce the need to spill to memory.

Pretty much every other RISC architectures has **at least 32 registers**, therefore it's worth dedicating one for the zero constant. We can see that: [SPARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) has `%g0`, [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Registers) has `$zero` or `$0`, [Itanium](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150727-00/?p=90821/) (strictly speaking not RISC but VLIW, but still tons of registers [128]) has `r0`, [RISC-V](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/risc-v/registers) has `x0`, [SH-5](http://www.iuma.ulpgc.es/%7Enunez/procmultimedia98-00/hitachi/sh5_whitepaper.pdf) has [R63](http://lars.nocrew.org/computers/processors/SuperH/cpush5v1.pdf), [Blackfin](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/processor-manuals/Blackfin_pgr_rev2.2.pdf) has `R0`,
[i860](https://www.realworldtech.com/intel-history-lesson/2/) has `R0`, [PA-RISC](http://www.robelle.com/library/smugbook/register.html) has `R0`, [ARC](http://www.radford.edu/%7Emhtay/CPSC352/Lecture_PDF/Ch04POCA.pdf) has `%r0`, [Motorola 88000](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/motorola/88000/MC88100_RISC_Microprocessor_Users_Manual_2ed_1990.pdf) has `r0`, [Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha#Registers) with 2 separate zero registers: integer `R31` and floating-point `F31`...

A slight deviation is PowerPC where `r0` means either the GPR0 or the number 0 depending on instructions. However Plan 9 for PowerPC diverges even further by [initializing `r0` to 0 by software](https://9p.io/sys/doc/asm.html)

- [Why the %r0 of SPARC or MIPS, is always 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19130790/995714)
- [How does a zero register improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24646101/995714)
- [Why MIPS uses R0 as "zero" when you could just XOR two registers to produce 0?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/293830/27052)

The only odd RISC architecture with 32 registers but *without a zero register* is [Intel](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/components/intel/i960/272483-001_Intel_i960_Jx_Microprocessor_Users_Manual_Sep94.pdf) [i960](http://www.nj7p.org/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/485276-007.pdf), but again the bizarre Plan 9 also [requires the R3 register to be set to 0 by software](https://9p.io/sys/doc/asm.html). Another weird beast is [OpenRISC](https://openrisc.io/architecture) where **R0 is also initialized to 0 by software**. This means that R0 should not be used as a destination because writes to it will destroy the value

The register 0 allows designers to remove many instructions, simplifying the hardware. For example we don't need `mov` any more, instead we can just `add` with zero and store in the destination. Negation is also now just a subtraction from zero. Writes to the zero register discard the results, and we don't need a separate `NOP` either. ARM and Intel i960 don't have a zero register so they have explicit `mov` instructions in the ISA

ARM was always an exception because it has only **16 registers** (actually ~12-13, since SP, PC... are included in the general purpose set), making an exclusive register for zero wasteful. Moreover ARM wasn't considered pure RISC because its instructions and addressing modes are too complex (LDM, STM, shift and conditional in every instructions...)

> Even though the ARM is a RISC architecture, it does not strictly follow the RISC principles as does the MIPS. For example, some of the ARM instructions such as `ldm` and `stm` are not simple instructions. In addition, it provides a large number of addressing modes and uses a somewhat complex instruction format
>
> [Guide to RISC Processors: for Programmers and Engineers](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=j6aVptEpdGkC&pg=PA145&dq=%22it%20does%20not%20strictly%20follow%20the%20RISC%20principles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzi6vvw8vdAhVBVrwKHfNoC4wQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22it%20does%20not%20strictly%20follow%20the%20RISC%20principles%22&f=false)

When Arm Holdings decided that Aarch64 would also have 32 registers, they'd definitely do the same thing to make the instruction set more RISCy and [more orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set). Now the PC, SP... are also separated, thus we have more than twice the registers compared to ARM. Making one of them a zero register made a lot of sense.

A similar case is the SuperH architecture, where the version SH-4 has 16 registers. When Renesas extended to it to 64 registers in SH-5 they also reserved R63 for the zero constant

Comment: The biggest still-relevant reason that ARM is less RISCy is because load-multiple / store-multiple do a variable number of loads or stores, and basically have to be micro-coded.  Complex addressing modes (like 2-register with scaling via the usual barrel-shifter) isn't a big deal for modern CPUs.  AArch64 dropped predication and ldm/stm, but kept the barrel shifter.  Of course, being RISCy wasn't their goal, it was a compact instruction set that can be efficiently implemented and get a lot done with each instruction.  (And most implementations still want to run 32-bit code so they need the HW)

Comment: Anyway, if you're just going to summarize one thing from that quote, for me it's `ldm`/`stm`, not addressing modes.

Comment: yes the quote is about load/store multiple, however I remember reading some threads about other complexities of ARM on reddit or somewhere but I haven't recheck it. Anyway my point is that ARM is making the architecture more RISCy while transitioning to 64-bit, and having a zero register is one of the steps

Answer (score 4):

To answer what I think is your headline question, **no** I don't think it's a particularly "safe" (useful) analogy to make.

The concept of ground in electrical engineering has very specific semantics and many related concepts, but only a very tangental relationship to a "fixed zero register" in that the number zero is involved in both cases.

Beyond the presence of zero in both concepts, I don't see a lot of use in the analogy. It almost certainly doesn't reflect the reality of how the register is implemented, and it doesn't let you map concepts from your knowledge of electrical engineering into ARM assembly programming. If you have a question about how the zero register works (for example, "what happens on writes?"), it seems very unlikely that you'll be able to answer it by reference to your analogy.

I don't know why the (unlinked) site used the terminology ***reference point** for zero*, but I think it safe to ignore the "reference point" language entirely. It's just zero. When you read it is zero, and when you write to it, it does nothing. The usefulness of this is explained in [fuz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411101/149138).

All that said, if you find this analogy a useful mental construct *for you*, then it's not wrong to use it in your *own* learning process!

Answer (score 3):

You can sort of think of the bits in this register as being hard-wired to ground.  But writing to it doesn't cause a short-circuit.  A better analogy is Unix `/dev/zero`: discard writes, reads as an infinite stream of zero bytes.

But no, it's not a "reference" in the sense that things are measured relative to it.  Logical `0` bits could exist in the CPU whether or not AArch64 had this register, and they aren't compared to it to determine if they're true/false.  Electrically, a logical `1` is normally a high voltage, and `0` = ground, so gates do compare their input to ground, and all `0` bits anywhere are equivalent to ground.  (This is probably a major oversimplification, and of course internally inside an ALU or something, bits might be inverted or not physically exist, only logically in some other representation).

So as an *analogy* it doesn't work at all.  As a description of how it's physically / electrically implemented, it doesn't totally work either.  It needs to discard writes without short circuiting.  And in a CPU with register-renaming, it needs to be special-cased in the RAT (register allocation table) to keep track of the fact that writes are discarded and dependency chains don't propagate through `xzr`.  If you ignore that, you could imagine a stand-in for SRAM cells with the input disconnected, and the output hardwired to zero.

---

It looks like clumsy wording; a better description would be that a zero-register is a fixed constant that silently discards writes.

Reading it gives you a fixed constant zero, which is occasionally useful (e.g. for storing zeros to memory without needing to zero a register first).  Unless that context would give you the `sp` alias for the same register number; I don't know AArch64 that well.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to answer *No*? The term *ground* has a very specific and somewhat complex meaning in electronic. I think it's better to discourage this thinking altogether. I'm not an EE, for what I've seen usually the output of a digital circuit is not really connected to ground but can be put at the same level of the ground by dissipating the energy somewhere else. That's how the inverting amplifier works for example (IIRC).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Good feedback, updated.  But in CMOS logic, the `0` / false state really is created by switching *on* a FET that connects the output to ground with near-zero resistance.  Some transient current flows to discharge the capacitance of the load, then ~none.  See Wikipedia's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS for an image of a 2-transistor NOT gate.   While both transistors are partially conducting mid switch, some current does flow from VCC to ground through them.  This is why CMOS logic only dissipates power *while switching*, other than static leakage of fully-off transistors.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: a CMOS NOT gate *is* an inverting amplifier, but instead of a resistor from Vcc, you have another transistor.  So with a high input, the transistor from Vcc has near-infinite resistance and the bottom transistor is conducting.  With low input, the bottom transistor is switched off.  But instead of powering the load through a fixed resistor like an inverting linear amp, current from Vcc flows through a fully-on transistor.

Comment: Related: [Why are NAND gates used to make AND gates in computers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/395230) explains why logic gates *aren't* built with transistor / resistor, and why inverting is necessary for fan-out / chaining of gates, so you can't just put 2 transistors in series from Vcc to output.

Comment: A CMOS NOT is not considered an inverting amplifier, they may look similar but they work on completely different principles.  
My point is that it makes no sense, at this zoom level, to talk about [Ground and things connected to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground) or that "Ground = 0" :) 
But I have been too zealous, CPUs don't need to drive high loads so of course in these designs a node at Ground is usually connected to it through some path
(but these path are not as simple as depicted in that NOT diagram).

Comment: By the way, this [RE of the 8085 register file](http://www.righto.com/2013/03/register-file-8085.html) may interest you.  
Out of topic: ECL is a different technology than CMOS it requires more power but it is way faster, that would be useful for some deep ALU circuits (like a multiplier
but not the register file) and could be switched on and off on demand with some overhead.