# How does the zero register stay zero in MIPS architecture?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, riscv

I would like to know how it's implemented for the zero register to stay zero no matter what.

In the `MIPS32® Architecture for Programmers Volume I: Introduction to the MIPS32® Architecture (pdf)`, it is said that:

> `r0` is hard-wired to a value of zero.

How does this `hardwire` work or "look like"?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. Perhaps there is another StackExchange site where this question would be suitable.

Comment: Instead of being backed by memory it's simply wires connected to ground (0 level).

Comment: [Is Zero Register 'zr' in aarch64 essentially ground?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52410521) is basically the same question about physical implementation of a zero register.  AArch64's zr is a bit trickier than MIPS: the same register-number encoding can mean stack pointer depending on context. But other than that, the answers cover the electrical-design aspects.

Comment: Also related: [Why MIPS uses R0 as "zero" when you could just XOR two registers to produce 0?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/293830) explains why it's useful to have a register that ignores writes and always reads as 0.

Comment: The zero register is special cased in the code of the hardware.  There are many ways to implement that as long as it has the effect that it reads as the value 0 whenever it is sourced (read).  It may or may not be a physical register, it may be special cased on writes as well as on reads.  It could be a constant value in the register file, or simply special cased in several places (read reg 1 & 2 in block diagrams).  It could be a real register forced to zero on reset, and special cased on write (write reg in block diagrams).  Or even a real register forced to zero every cycle.

Comment: If you wrote an interpreter or simulator (which is what hardware is) in C or Java, you'd also special case the zero register in some manner, with one of the above options or something else.