# Why no zero register instruction on x86

Tags: assembly, x86

Why does the x86 instruction set not have a dedicated instruction for zeroing a register?
Devs have to use idioms like `xor reg, reg` to perform this type of function.

Comment: What other ISAs have a special opcode just for zeroing a register?  AVR has `clr reg`, but that's [just an alias](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-76F9CCD0-F574-4805-A7AF-ECE910527BAA.html) for xor aka EOR with itself.  (AVR does have an `ldi` load-immediate, but it only works with registers 16-31, with only a 4 bit register-number field.  But EOR can work on any register, 0-31, since it has room for two 5-bit register fields.)

Comment: You know x86 has `mov reg, 0`, right?  It's less efficient due to larger code-size in x86's variable-length machine code, which led to CPUs [optimizing xor-zeroing even more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) than `mov` zeroing.  (Although [Golden Cove P-cores in Alder Lake](https://chipsandcheese.com/2021/12/02/popping-the-hood-on-golden-cove/) do eliminate mov zeroing now, too.)

Comment: So if anything, I'd say x86 *does* have a special way to zero registers (xor special-cased by CPUs) which is different from the best way to put any non-zero value into a register.

Comment: What would it gain?  `xor reg, reg` and `sub reg, reg` are 2 bytes and are the fastest kind of simple ALU instruction.  The only way they could have improved it was to create a 1-byte instruction, but then there would have to be one for each of the 8 registers, so that uses up 8 of your 256 opcode bytes right there.  They did do this for `push/pop`, `inc/dec`, `mov reg, imm`, and (inexplicably) for `xchg ax, reg`, but opcode space is a precious resource and not to be squandered.  (And x86-64 had to reclaim some of it by removing single-byte `inc/dec`.)

Comment: @Dess: Can you clarify your question in light of these comments?  I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.  If it's really just why xor is used to zero registers instead of a more "normal looking" instruction, see the link in my earlier comment: it's an optimization.

Comment: I asked because: A) It's a very common operation to do. B) xor sets flags. C) Although asm devs are used to it, it looks weird to use xor to zero a reg. D) It takes special clarification from the manufacturers that, yes, xor is the best way to zero a reg; with a dedicated instruction, people wouldn't have any doubt.

Comment: It's customary among CPU manufacturers to tell how to better program their CPUs and assume programmers know their CPUs. So points C and D are void, you are programming a HW device, not an abstraction. Point A seems moot: zeroing is common (loops, sum, indexing) but is common enough? What about loading a pointer (which is, just like zeroing, an instance of setting a register to a value)? Point B is true, but it's usually possible to just reorder a few instructions to fix it or to fallback to using `mov` if spilling data around is to expensive.

Comment: Re: "What other ISAs have a special opcode just for zeroing a register?" The m68k has `clr.s dx`, (with `clr.l dx` being slower than `moveq #0, dx` ...)

Comment: For 8-bit registers, `mov reg, 0` is 2 bytes, same as xor.  For 16-bit registers on 8086, `mov reg, 0` costs 3 bytes, only one more than xor.  IDK if xor-zeroing was intended by Steve Morse when he laid out the ISA, or if that was a later optimization choice by programmers who found a more compact way to do things.  The latter is certainly possible, but check his book (for free on his web site https://stevemorse.org/8086/) and/or an 8008 to 8086 history article from 1980 by some of the architects: https://stevemorse.org/8086history/8086history.doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, CPU architectures have been minimalistic.

The op-code space is the most valuable resource of a CPU: the number of available 8-bit numbers is very small, so every op-code counts. A feature that would reserve an extra opcode would have to be extremely valuable in order to be considered. If the same feature can be achieved by an already existing instruction, then this is always a winner.

So, every single feature that is offered by a CPU is almost never for the programmer's convenience, but instead in order to achieve something that would otherwise be impossible, or in order to achieve better performance. (And of course these two are equivalent, because everything is possible given enough clock cycles, so ultimately there is only one goal, and this is performance.)

The `xor reg, reg` idiom of x86/x64 satisfies this minimalistic need: it does get the job done, and its performance cannot be improved.

The fact that "Devs have to use idioms like xor reg, reg to perform this type of function" is of no concern whatsoever: every single instruction that you use in Assembly is an idiom. Give or take one (or a few, or even many) does not make any difference.

Comment: I once came across an architecture that had a special register that was always zero, so as to make it very easy to obtain a zero. I always found this extremely amusing, extremely arcane, and I highly doubted its usefulness. If anyone knows what architecture that was, and what practical considerations lead to this weird construct, please do tell.

Comment: Could be any of MIPS, PowerPC, RISC-V, AArch64, or various other RISCs.  It's not at all rare.  On 3-operand ISAs with a FLAGS register, it means they don't need separate `sub` and `cmp` opcodes, you just `sub r0, r10, r11` to discard the non-FLAGS result.  On ISAs like MIPS and RISC-V (no FLAGS), it still means they don't need a separate opcode for mov-immediate, they can just use `addiu $t1, $zero, -123`.  And it's something to compare against for `beq $t1, $zero, target`, instead of having a separate `beqz` opcode.  [How does a zero register improve perf?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24646101)

Comment: [pretty much all RISC ISAs have a zero register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438497/995714)

Comment: Ok, it is embarrassing that I did not know that this is a common characteristic in RISC architectures, but now my question is: Doesn't this essentially prevent you from addressing a (very valuable, in my little mind) register? Do they have the freedom to do so because they have so many registers? (Having more registers than you know what to do with them is such an alien concept from someone familiar with x86!)

Comment: @PeterCordes ^^

Comment: @phuclv ^ ^ ^ ^

Comment: @MikeNakis: A zero-register is usually only found on machine with 32 registers, not 16 (ARM32 doesn't have one). 32 is enough that you're not going to miss one, and presumably the transistor savings enabled by fewer opcodes could maybe let it clock higher, or be cheaper to manufacture (smaller die).  MIPS was one of the earlier RISC designs, and also basically reserved 2 more registers to be asynchronously clobbered by interrupts instead of having special state elsewhere and special instructions to read it; I presume fitting the pipeline onto a chip at all was a challenge in the early 80s.